Where to store the JWT in react that I get from my backend secure?
I learned new axios and interceptors and want to save my jwt in my react application where I get this from my backend.
But how should I store it secure and I want it when I close the browser that the people is still logged in but how can I say to my application get the token from anywhere and stay logged in.
I saw some tutorials where they use the jwt from localstorage but I dont want to store it there.
€: and when I get it from cookie how can I persist store it in my application or do I have everytime check for cookie ?
